# Is There A Japanese Word ( preferably a single Kanji ) For Owner of Black Stallion?

Tags: translation, kanji, word-requests

I am looking for a Japanese word, preferably a single Kanji character to mean "owner of black male horse". I checked some dictionaries, but could not find a single word for it.

Currently, I found the following on jisho.org and Google:

> 驪 = Black horse
>   牡馬 (Boba) = Male horse (stallion)
>   黒 (Kuro) = Black
>   闆 = Owner
>   馬主 = Horse Owner
>
> 馬 = Horse (Google Translate)

Just one more question, can I just put these kanji characters in sequence to get the meaning I want? e.g. 牡馬 + 闆 = 牡馬闆 (black horse owner?)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you think there might be a single word/kanji that describes all of that?

Comment: @user3856370 as far as I know kanji characters often have independent meanings, so I was just curious if there was a kanji for that phrase. Or at least two or three kanjis (as few characters as possible) that can describe that?

Answer (score 5):

The kanji like 驪 or 闆 seem to be very rare and are unlikely to be known by a common person. You can notice that there are no entries for words containing those kanji, only some place/people names.

While a somewhat unusual combination, I *think* 黒馬主 (kuro uma nushi) will be probably understood (note that it doesn't specify that the horse is male).

In general, stacking up kanji like that does not always work; you may get better understanding by combining proper words with particles, e.g. 青毛の牡馬の主 (owner of a stallion with black coat).

P.S. *Please* don't put this on a tattoo.

Comment: I'm +1'ing this just for "*Please* don't put this on a tattoo".  Yes, OP, *PLEASE* don't put this on a tattoo.

Comment: What is the coat about? Admitedly it is supposed to be embroidered on a karategi. Is that fine?

Comment: @codezombie when a stallion is black, isn't it a given that it's coat would be black?

Comment: @Leebo OK, but horses don't usually wear coats, that's why it seemed unnatural to me. Maybe it is the only way its color could be conveyed.

Comment: @codezombie Are you pulling my leg >_> A coat is what you call an animal's fur. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equine_coat_color

Comment: Sorry @Leebo you are right